# Docker-compose - how to delete the services built from docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, service, docker-compose

I was testing a project with multiple containers & services...

First, I ran the command 'docker-compose up' against the file docker-compose.yml...and have all the services built and tested as expected.

Then I ran 'docker-compose ps --services' and got the list of services being built:

*service1*

*service2*

*service3*

Just wondering, is there a way to remove the services so that to rebuild them for next run/testing?

Comment: `docker-compose down` # Stop and remove containers, networks..

Comment: I tried that using:
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
But still found all the services by 'docker-compose ps --services'...did I understand something wrong with the services?